# Scraping data using selenium giving Enable Javascript Message

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a url using Selenium Python.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--incognito')

url_list = "https://memphissymphony.secure.force.com/ticket/#/events/a0S3o00001J8qqiEAB"

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get(url_list)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    driver.quit()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

After scraping I am getting the data with the content

**Content**

```
.
.
.
.
</div>
<noscript>
<h1>Please enable Javascript in your browser. Our site won't work without it.</h1>
</noscript>
</div>
<div class="pts-footer w-100 p-2 bg-dark text-light" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">
<p class="text-center m-0">
<small>
<span>Copyright ©</span> 2021 Memphis Symphony Orchestra
                                </small>
</p>
.
.
.
```

Also in the chrome browser javascript is enabled.

[image]

I added the options for enabling JavaScript but still its not working. How can I scrape the whole data from this url

Comment: You are scraping the whole html. That's part of it the html structure. Read about `<noscript>` tags [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are no issues or errors. It's performing exactly as it should.

Comment: @chitown88 what to do for extracting the data in that case

Comment: So **if**  the site/page is dynamic, you either get the data from the source through an api if available, or use Selenium to allow the page to render (as you are doing here). `requests-html` (link [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/)) is also an option. But I haven't used it as I like to use Spyder IDE and it's not functional within that.

Comment: @chitown thanks i will check